# How I can keep my nextjs typescript (interfaces / types) with nodejs server typescript models (interfaces / types)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

In our **`frontend`** project we are using nextjs with typescript and in server side with microservice we are using `nodejs` for one of microservices and its implemented with typescript.

I want to automate the process of create and update interfaces with `nextjs app` that they are defined in serverside because its using typescript and in nextjs we are using typescript too and I want using that implemented interfaces for request and response in api calls in frontend which that I relay to that automated created types/interfaces.

Finally I should point that it's not **`monorepo`** project and frontend and backend are developing in separate environments.

Has any body experience about this issue of recommendation about any tools or packages that can handle this purpose?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in separate repositories then really you need a contract between the FE service and the BE service, and contract analysis during your pipeline to ensure that the FE microservice is compatible with whatever is running in your environment. You can use something like PACT to do that.